# Error: Configuration cannot be run until project has been synced

Tags: plugins, pycharm, bazel

I am using PyCharm with the Bazel plugin. When trying to set up the command to run my program there is a message saying

> Error: Configuration cannot be run until project has been synced.

Ignoring that message and trying to run of course results in a crash. I've tried running file>>synchronize but that seems to have no effect. How do I sync my project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to "File > Import Bazel Project..." to operate in a Bazel environment from inside PyCharm, Goland, etc. You cannot just create a Run/Debug Bazel configuration.